# Pure js. Get width of element and use it in a scroll

Tags: javascript, html

Currently I cannot get my head wrapped around something probably really simple.

To get a good view, just below is the html.

It's got a slider with `#sliderScroll` as ID with a fixed width and overflow scroll.

Within there are multiple `div.text-image-item`, which are blocks with a width size that fluctuates based on the screen size of the user.

```
<div id="sliderScroll" class="slider">
   <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 1 </div>
   <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 2 </div>
   <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 3 </div>
   <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 4 </div>
</div>
```

With a button I want the user to be able to scroll horizontal. 
I want the amount of pixels to scroll to represent the width of a block (`.text-image-item`), which fluctuates based on the user's screen size.

I'm trying to get the width of this `.text-image-item` block and use that in a scrollLeft function.

What I got so far:

```
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('scrollLeft');

buttonLeft.onclick = function () {
    var itemWidth = document.getElementsByClassName('text-image-item').offsetWidth;
    console.log(itemWidth);
    document.getElementById('sliderScroll').scrollLeft -= itemWidth;
};
```

If I set a fixed number for `var itemWidth`, it looks like it's working. 
But I want to get the width of the div with the class `.text-image-item`.

I added the `console.log` to see if the var outputs the correct number, but it's only returning `undefined`.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm scratching my head over here since I'm not quite sure where it's going wrong.

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('text-image-item')` returns a `NodeList`, which in this case contains 4 nodes.  The `NodeList` does not have an `offsetWidth`.  Only individual elements have a width.

Comment: Thank you Amy. I didn't know this wouldn't work with multiple elements, even though they all have the same width.

Comment: They are not guaranteed to have the same width.  If you believe that to be reliably the case, though, just pick one of the elements and use its width.

Comment: Will do indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName('text-image-item')` returns a `NodeList`, which in this case contains 4 nodes. The `NodeList` does not have an `offsetWidth`. Only individual elements have a width.

You will need to pick one of the nodes and use its width instead.  You can do this by picking a valid index:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('text-image-item')[0].offsetWidth
```

For more information about `NodeList`, check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElemenetsByClassName()` returns a `NodeList`, but you perform operations on it as it is an Element. Also, it looks like you only need one of the elements of the class `.text-image-item` so using [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) like `document.querySelector('.text-image-item')` will suffice as it will return the first element with that class name.

Try:

```js
const buttonLeft = document.getElementById('scrollLeft');

buttonLeft.onclick = function() {
  let itemWidth = document.querySelector('.text-image-item').offsetWidth;
};
```

```html
<button id="scrollLeft">Scroll Left</button>
<div id="sliderScroll" class="slider">
  <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 1 </div>
  <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 2 </div>
  <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 3 </div>
  <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 4 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to take the elements that you have in the scroll up to the current element, and sum their width. Then you can use that to set the scroll width. That way, you can have elements with any width you like, and still get to the element you need.

```js
const sumByFunction = f => (p, c) => p + f(c);
const getOffsetWidth = element => element.offsetWidth;

const querySelector = element =>
  selector =>
    Array.from(element.querySelectorAll(selector))

const sumOffsetWidths = sumByFunction(getOffsetWidth)

const scrollNext = (element) => {
  let currentScroll = 0;
  const selector = querySelector(element);
  
  return () => {
    currentScroll++;
    const scrollTarget = selector('.text-image-item')
      .slice(0, currentScroll)
      .reduce(sumOffsetWidths, 0)
      
    element.scrollLeft = scrollTarget;
  }
};

document
  .getElementById('scroller')
  .onclick = scrollNext(document.getElementById('sliderScroll'));
```

```css
#sliderScroll {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.text-image-item {
  border: solid 2px rgba(20, 20, 30, 0.4);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70vw;
}

#scroller {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="sliderScroll" class="slider">
   <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 1 </div>
   <div class="text-image-item" style="width: 2000px; background-color: rgba(50, 100, 200, 0.4);"> Content block 2 </div>
   <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 3 </div>
   <div class="text-image-item"> Content block 4 </div>
</div>
<button id="scroller">Scroll next</button>
```